How to test function that mocks Get-ChildItem w/ -File parameter?
This Pester test:
BeforeAll {
    function Get-HtmlFileDetail {
        param (
            [string[]]$Path = 'E:\Domains',
            [string[]]$Include = 'Alive*.html'
        )
        return Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Include $Include -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Drive    = Split-Path -Path $PSItem.FullName -Qualifier
                Parent   = Split-Path (Split-Path $PSItem.FullName -Parent) -Leaf
                FileName = Split-Path -Path $PSItem.FullName -Leaf
                BodyText = (Get-Content -Path $PSItem.FullName -Raw | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=<body>).*?(?=</body>)').Matches.Value
            }
        }
    }
}
Describe 'FileSytem' {
    Context 'Get-HtmlFileDetail' {
        Context 'when path and include are NOT specified' {
            BeforeAll {
                Mock -CommandName Get-ChildItem -MockWith { }
            }
            It 'should use defaults' {
                Get-HtmlFileDetail | Should -Invoke -CommandName Get-ChildItem -Times 1 -ParameterFilter {
                    $Path -eq 'E:\Domains' -and $Include -eq 'Alive*.html'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Errors with:

[-] FileSytem.Get-HtmlFileDetail.when path and include are NOT specified.should use defaults 620ms (513ms|107ms)
ParameterBindingException: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.


I'm not able to reproduce the issue. -File is a dynamic parameter based on the path. Are you running this on Windows or maybe a unix CI where E:\Domains would not be considered a filepath?

@FrodeF. I am running this on Windows PC, my computer does not have an E:\ Drive, and I thought I could use a Mock to get around that fact. This is my first attempt to at coding anything Microsoft. I see about_FileSystem_Provider documentation mentions File as Dynamic parameter for Get-ChildItem. Thanks for highlighting -- I missed that nuance. I can't say I understand what that really means or how to use that fact to mitigate the problem with my test just now, but it gives me another avenue to pursue.

I think Pester tries to bind the parameters of Get-ChildItem, even though it will be mocked. As the path does not exist, it can't bind the dynamic parameter -File, so it throws a ParameterBindingException and the test fails.
You can assert that parameters have correct default values by using Should -HaveParameter instead of mocking:
BeforeAll {
    function Get-HtmlFileDetail {
        param (
            [string[]]$Path = 'E:\Domains',
            [string[]]$Include = 'Alive*.html'
        )
        return Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Include $Include -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Drive    = Split-Path -Path $PSItem.FullName -Qualifier
                Parent   = Split-Path (Split-Path $PSItem.FullName -Parent) -Leaf
                FileName = Split-Path -Path $PSItem.FullName -Leaf
                BodyText = (Get-Content -Path $PSItem.FullName -Raw | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=<body>).*?(?=</body>)').Matches.Value
            }
        }
    }
}
Describe 'FileSytem' {
    Context 'Get-HtmlFileDetail' {
        Context 'when path and include are NOT specified' {
            It 'should use defaults' {
                Get-Command Get-HtmlFileDetail | Should -HaveParameter -ParameterName Path -DefaultValue 'E:\Domains'
                Get-Command Get-HtmlFileDetail | Should -HaveParameter -ParameterName Include -DefaultValue 'Alive*.html'
            }
        }
    }
}

